# Why have negative-valued signed literals?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

This is a simple question, but I haven't really seen an answer before. In Verilog (or SystemVerilog for that matter), one may declare a literal and indicate the number of bits used. Some examples are:

```
reg [3:0] x = 4'b1101; // (1)
reg [3:0] y = 4'd13;   // (2)
```

Here the registers x and y are declared and they hold the same value initially. There is also a signed modifier that may be used. Some examples using it are:

```
reg signed [3:0] a = 4'sb0101; // (3)
reg signed [3:0] b = 4'sd5;    // (4)
```

Now, my question is how to represent a negative value using the decimal notation. Let's say we want to initialize registers c and d to -3. Is this correct?

```
reg signed [3:0] c = 4'sb1101; // (5)
reg signed [3:0] d = -4'sd3;   // (6)
```

The above code compiles and runs in my current version of ActiveHDL. To me, it seems to semantically suggest the following: the representation of the number 0011 is negated (bits inverted and one added) to obtain 1101 (the actual literal I want to represent). Notice, we have employed the negation operator in this. I have often wondered if there is another way to represent the number directly. I have tried `4'sd(-3)` which seems cleaner to me, because now the width and the represented value are decoupled. However, this gave me syntax errors. I already have the work around in the initialization labeled (6), but that still begs the question...

Why should there be a signed modifier for width-specified literals if the width-specified literals cannot contain negative values (without operators acting on them)?

In other words, how is the literal `-4'sd3` superior to (or just different from) the literal `-4'd3`?

Alternative solution: Show me how to represent a negative valued signed literal in a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `4'(-3)` This is casting an expression to a specified width, 4.

As the LRM states, the `s` modifier does not affect the bit pattern represented; just its interpretation. It would make a difference if you had

```
module top;

  reg signed  [5:0] a;
  initial begin
    a = -4;
    $display(a<4'b1101);
    $display(a<4'sb1101);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: That is an interesting alternative. I've used that many times when concatenating a signed value. It didn't occur to me while I was writing the question. Does the negative sign imply that the final value will be considered signed in an expression? So something like a = b * 4'(-1) would result in a signed multiplication (assuming b is signed)? I guess I can try it myself.

Comment: Yes, The LRM say the signedness passes through unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Both `-4'sd3` and `-4d3` are identical.

The numbers specified with the base format shall be treated as signed integers if the s designator is included or as unsigned integers if the base format only is used.

> The s designator does not affect the bit pattern specified, only its
> interpretation. A plus or minus operator preceding the size constant
> is a unary plus or minus operator. A plus or minus operator between
> the base format and the number is illegal syntax.

```
    8'd-6   // this is illegal syntax
    -4'sd15 // -15, equivalent to -4'd15, or '0001'
    16'sd?  // the same as 16'sbz
```

Comment: Karan, I'm assuming you meant to say that -4'sd3 and -4'd3 are the same? (You are missing the ' character.) Thanks for the response though.